# Laravel and Vue - Passing auth()->user()->name to Vue template returns non-object

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I am having this error when passing the `auth()->user()->name` to a vue template. I also tried the meta method and it still shows the same error. I'm sure that I'm currently logged-in with my system.

**Welcome.blade.php**

```
<script>
    window.user = @json(
    [
        'user'=> auth()->user()->name ,
    ]
    );
</script>
```

**App.js**

```
console.log('user object form vue', window.user);

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  render: h=>h(App),
  vuetify,
  router,
  store,
});
```

routes **web.php**

```
Route::get('/{any}', 'HomeController@index')->where('any', '.*')->name('landing');
```

**HomeController.blade.php**

```
public function index()
{
    return view('welcome');
}
```

And this is what I got

[image]

If I try only using this line `'user'=> auth()->user()` the `console.log` returns an undefined.

Does it have something to do with my **web.php** having no `middleware->('auth')`? I'm currently using an `api 'auth'`

Comment: You should put the user object in vuex store instead I think putting it in the window object is not a good idea.

Comment: Will do. I'm still exploring on how I would implement it with my current work around (please see answer).

Answer (score 0):

Okay I made an alternative way to make it work without the `<script>`

**User Model**

```
  protected $with = ['roles', 'permissions'];
```

**API**

```
 Route::get('user', function (Request $request) {
    return $request->user();
  });
```